# Can limit superior and limit inferior exist for an unbounded sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Can limit superior and limit inferior exist for an unbounded sequence? If not then why doesn't text books say limit inferior and superior of a bounded sequence instead of limit superior and inferior of a sequence?

Comment: They may be $\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: They exist  in $\overline{\mathbf R}=\mathbf R\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Sort of the whole point to $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ is that they are defined for *any* sequence of reals. You need to keep in mind that $\infty$ and $-\infty$ are allowed as values.

If $\sup a_n=\infty$ then $\limsup a_n=\infty$. This  is clear from the definition: If $\sup_na_n=\infty$ then for every $n$ we have $\sup_{j>n}a_j=\infty$, hence $$\limsup a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{j>n}a_j=\lim_{n\to\infty}\infty=\infty.$$

Answer (score 3):

$\limsup$ and $\liminf$ always exists for any real sequence. For $(a_j)_{j=0}^\infty$,
$$ \liminf_{j \to \infty} a_j = \lim_{m \to \infty} \inf_{j \geq m} a_j
$$
Since $\left(\inf_{j \geq m}\right)_{m=0}^\infty$ form an increasing sequence, its limit exists. (Possibly equal to $\pm \infty$) and likewise for $\limsup$.

Since $(a_j)_{j=0}^\infty$ is bounded, its $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ are guaranteed to be real numbers and not $\pm\infty$.

Comment: so with the help of extended real number system we can also define limit superior and inferior for unbounded sequences too as they allow positive and negative negative infinity?

Comment: @saqib Yes. They serve as the upper and lower bounds of all real numbers.